# Java enum value not recognized by IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, enums

I have a class named `Permission` with an enum named `Type`. `Type` has a value called `Calendar`. When I try to access `Calendar` from the enum inside another file, IntelliJ resolves it as a `java.util.Calendar` object. I manually imported the `Calendar` enum value but it remains unused. Any suggestions on how to fix this will help. Thanks!

Code example:
Permission.java

```
public class Permission {

    String name;
    Type type;

    public Permission(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Type.java

```
public enum Type {
    Camera,
    Calendar
}
```

App.java

```
import static com.avi.enumTest.Type.Camera;
import static com.avi.enumTest.Type.Calendar;

import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permission p1 = new Permission("camera", Camera);
        Permission p2 = new Permission("calendar", Calendar);

        List<Permission> permList = new ArrayList<>();
        permList.add(p1);
        permList.add(p2);

        for (Permission p: permList) {
            switch (p.type) {
                case Camera:
                    System.out.println("1");
                    break;
                case Calendar:
                    System.out.println("2");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("3");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(p.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Calendar` in App.java is being seen as a `java.util.Calendar` object. This is only happening in IntelliJ. Tried running it VSCode it works fine with the imports. Only IntelliJ does not use the imports and defaults to `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Refer to it in your code as `Type.Calendar` and import `Type` instead of `Calendar`.  That's what you should do with enums anyway, regardless of whether there's a name clash.

Comment: And style wise, enum values are commonly typed with all caps like constants. Following common Java code formatting would have saved you from the conflict with java.util.Calendar.

Comment: This Question needs example code, a *minimal* example.

Comment: Create a bug report over at JetBrains if this only affects IntelliJ